# Laravel: Error in sending Mail using gmail

Tags: php, laravel, forms, email, gmail

My system submits a form which contains data that will be sent through the controller:

```
Mail::to( $requests->input('email') )->send( new ResultMail($requests));
```

**[This error shows up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pgp8I.png)** whenever I try to submit my form data. I've double checked my user credentials in .env and they are correct.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31091096/push-notification-crypto-error

Comment: Don't hide error details as image links. Provide them as copyable, searchable text.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused due to a bad configuration of SSL in your server. Make sure curl is installed on it and that .crt file exists.